# How to add a private function in a backbone.js model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to make a function private in backbone, so that it is only exposed to the model itself and also have access to `this` ?

How can I make `updateTime` private?

```
   var Timeline = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: 'servertime/',

        start: function(){
            this.fetch({
                success: function(timeline, response){
                    timeline.updateTime();
                    setInterval(function() {
                        timeline.updateTime();
                    }, 60 * 1000);
                }
            });
        },

        updateTime: function(){  //How can I make this private?
            this.time = ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping it all up in a self-invoking anonymous function, this way you are sure that updateTime is private:

```
(function() {
  var updateTime = function(){  // this stays private to this anonymous function
    this.time = ...
  },
  Timeline = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'servertime/',

    start: function(){
      this.fetch({
        success: function(timeline, response){
          updateTime.call(timeline);
          setInterval(function() {
            updateTime.call(timeline);
          }, 60 * 1000);
        }
      });
    }
  });

})();
```

Comment: this example is wrong since `updateTime` is not a timeline method anymore and `this` has the wrong context.

Comment: Critical to note `updateTime.call(timeline)` to ensure that the proper context is passed to `updateTime`.

Answer (score 7):

You can make `updateTime` a private *function* but not a private *method*.
I also recommend to prepend an underscore to make clear that its a private function.

```
(function() {
  function _updateTime(timeline){
    timeline.time = ...
  }

  Timeline = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'servertime/',

    start: function(){
      this.fetch({
        success: function(timeline, response){
          _updateTime(timeline);
          setInterval(function() {
            _updateTime(timeline);
          }, 60 * 1000);
        }
      });
    }
  });

})();
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the specificity regarding *function* vs *method*.

Comment: Adding an underscore *in no way* makes it clear it's a private function; however grouping all such functions into an object called _private or PRIVATE (but not 'private' since that is a reserved word) would, such that the function could be invoked as _private.updateTime() or PRIVATE.updateTime()

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: I disagree. Prefixing a method with an underscore by convention suggests it is private, even if it is publicly accessible. I’ve read this in JS design pattern books.

Comment: In this example, Timeline is being set as an explicit global. If you're going todo use this closure method, you may want to look into requireJS or another AWD lib.